# Is there a way to change the background color for the text editors in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, text-editor

I have Eclipse Kepler Mac version. In the text editor, I see a black background, which is really annoying me. I went to Window-->Preferences-->Text Editors-->Appearance color option to change the back ground color, but I don't see the setting helping me much. Is there a way to change the background color for the text editor?

Comment: What theme are you using - `Preferences > General > Appearance`?

Comment: I have the Theme:Mac. I tried change the theme to default, classic i don't see any difference in the Text editor background color

Comment: The Mac theme is normally black text on a white background (certainly is on my Mac). Perhaps try one of the other themes to see what happens.

Comment: @greg-449: i did but no difference and i restarted eclipse